# Path of saved file in a unit test with Junit

Tags: java, file, unit-testing, junit

In a Java application, I have a method of a class that saves a file just using its name.

```
public void doSomething(){
    final File file = new File("XXX"+(new Random().next())+".txt");
    file.createNewFile();
}
```

Then, in a unit test with **JUnit 4**, I run the class that execute the method and I see a file created with name `XXX.txt` in the root folder of the project.

```
@Test
public void doSomethingTest() throws Exception{
  //call doSomething();
  Path path = //to project folder
  Files.delete(path);
}
```

How can I get this path dynamically such that I can use a `@After` method to delete it?

Comment: Is just calling `new File('XXX.txt').delete()` not working from the test?

Comment: I said that I have a method in a class, not in the method annotated with @Test

Comment: @mat_boy it's unclear what you're asking. Whether the file is created from the test class or not is irrelevant. If it's named XXX.txt, you can execute new File("XXX.txt").delete() from the test, and it will be deleted. I **guess** that the problem is that you don't know the name of the file, because it's dynamically generated in the method under test. If that's the case, make that clear in the question. Post real code instead of fake code. So that we know **how** it's dynamically generated.

Comment: The name is created using an UUID. So I don't know it in advance. So yes, I'll update the querstion

Comment: There's always the option of not touching the file system entirely. Depending on what you want to test, it might be useful for you to wrap your file operations into a separate class, and mock it out.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The simplest way to do is to make your code testable by allowing it to inject the base directory where to create files.

Instead of

```
public Foo() {
}

public void doSomething() {
    final File file = new File("XXX" + (new Random().next()) + ".txt");
    file.createNewFile();
}
```

Use

```
private File baseDirectory;

public Foo() {
    this(new File("."));
}

public Foo(File baseDirectory) {
    this.baseDirectory = baseDirectory;
}

public void doSomething() {
    final File file = new File(baseDirectory, "XXX" + (new Random().next()) + ".txt");
    file.createNewFile();
}
```

Now your test can create a temporary empty directory, pass it to the constructor, call the method, check the files and delete them after the test.

This is probably a feature you would want anyway, because always writing in the current directory doesn't seem like a good idea to me.

Answer (score 4):

I recommend, as was already suggested, to change the source code and pass the parent folder from outside, preferably in the class constructor.

If for some reason you cannot do it, then you can try to override the [user.dir](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html) system property which controls the current working directory, that is where your files will be created by default.

Note that the `user.dir` is global, so changing it will affect all the classes. For example, you won't be able to run your test concurrently.

Also in JUnit you can use the [TemporaryFolder](http://junit.org/apidocs/org/junit/rules/TemporaryFolder.html) rule which would create a temporary directory before the test starts and delete it after the test finishes.

Example (copy-paste from the javadoc):

```
public static class HasTempFolder {
     @Rule
     public TemporaryFolder folder = new TemporaryFolder();

     @Test
     public void testUsingTempFolder() throws IOException {
         File createdFile = folder.newFile("myfile.txt");
         File createdFolder = folder.newFolder("subfolder");
         // ...
     }
}
```

Comment: Interesting, but the folder is defined in the method that I'm testing. I cannot pass the temporary folder to the method.

Comment: I recommend, as was already suggested, to change the source code and pass the parent folder from outside preferably in the class constructor.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [file.getAbsolutePath()](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/io/file_getabsolutepath.htm) to get the complete file path, expose it as a method and then delete it in the junit test.

Comment: The file is created in the method that I test! I don't return the method

Comment: Ok then, even better: Make the file variable a class variable (instead of a method variable) and then delete it in the @ After method using file.delete().  Dont forget to check for null in the @ After. ie: if (file!=null)file.delete();

Comment: Doesn't seems to be a clean solution. I don't need to have it as a class variable. And I will create multiple files, the name will be stored in a db most likely

Comment: If, as you say in your question, you need to delete the file in the @ After method, then you need a class variable. If you are creating multiple files in methods, use an ArrayList<File> and add files to this list as you create them, and delete then in the @ After method.  You can also have an ArrayList<String> in which you store file paths instead of ArrayList<File>.  But both need to be class level variables.

Comment: I just need to get the path of project root, that is where the file is automatically saved

Comment: You can get the path from getAbsoluteParh () method,  as mentioned in my answer

Answer (score 0):

You can use  Apache's commons-io. It has a FileUtils class that will do what you want.

Here is an example , implementation and its test
`

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

public class FileSave {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        FileSave fileSave = new FileSave();

        fileSave.saveFile("test.txt");
    }

    public void saveFile(String fileName) throws IOException {
        final File file = new File(fileName);
        file.createNewFile();
        System.out.println("Hello");
    }
}
```

`

Test file

`

```
import java.io.File;

import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;

public class FileSaveTest {


    @Test
    public void checkFileSaved() throws Exception{
        FileSave fileSave = new FileSave();
        fileSave.saveFile("test.txt");
        Assert.assertTrue(FileUtils.deleteQuietly(new File("test.txt")));
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

`

the method **FileUtils.deleteQuietly** will return true when it delete , otherwise false.

Comment: But the name of the file is not available outside of the method. In your example it is

Comment: Passing file name as parameter is good idea. So that it will be tightly coupled. And can be reusable to create any type of file name